# Why am I unable to find html element with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am having a weird issue with Python and Selenium. I am accessing the URL `https://www.biggerpockets.com/users/JarridJ1`. When you click more it shows further content. I can understand that it is a React-based website. When I view it on browser and doa  *View Source* I can see the required stuff in a react element `<div data-react-class="Profile/Header/Header" data-react-props="{&quot`. I tried to automate Firefox via Selenium but I could not even get with that as well. 
Check the screenshot:

[image]
Below is the code I tried:

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def parse(u):
    print('Processing... {}'.format(u))
    driver.get(u)
    sleep(2)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.save_screenshot('bp.png')
    print(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Bypass OS security model
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')  #
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    parse('https://www.biggerpockets.com/users/JarridJ1')
```

Comment: As per the code you are trying to fetch the page source right? So what is the issue that you are facing or what is the error that you are getting

Comment: @SameerArora If you do a page source `view-source:https://www.biggerpockets.com/users/JarridJ1` within browser, you will find text like `Jarrid.business@gmail.com` but when you check html returned by Sleenium, it is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one but I found a way to get to the element you have highlighted.  Still not sure why `driver.page_source` is not return what you are looking for.

```
def parse(u):
    print('Processing... {}'.format(u))
    driver.get(u)
    sleep(2)
    get_everything = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
    for element in get_everything:
        print(element .get_attribute('innerHTML'))

    #html = driver.page_source
    #driver.save_screenshot('bp.png')
    #print(html)
```

---

Below is my standalone example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Path\To\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.biggerpockets.com/users/JarridJ1")
time.sleep(5)
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-react-class='Profile/Header/Header']")
b = a.get_attribute("data-react-props")
print(b)
c = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
for i in c:
    print(i.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: I have updated the question. The required text is present though not visible. I just attached the screenshot. I did not click more for it.

Comment: @Volatil3 I think I understand better what you are looking for now. See the updated answer.

Comment: Wow, yes this works. Though it is not so relevant can I do similar without using Selenium and use `requests` and `bs4` instead?. I mean `a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-react-class='Profile/Header/Header']")`?

Comment: I find that `requests` does not work well for React hosted sites.